# android studio serial communication with arduino via usb

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arduino

i am trying to pass data between my arduino nano and my app via usb.
im using https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial/ library.

after a couple of trys using the example code provided I tried testing for the problem
my test code:

```
UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
    if (usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
       Log.d(TAG, "findSerialPortDevice() usbManager returned empty device list." );
     }
```

in my menifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" android:required="true"/>
```

The problem is that the UsbManager is allways empty and i think that the phone didnt detect the
usb devise.

I used both my arduino and my computer as the usb device
and tried using my pocophone, samsung tablet and another samsung phone.
and I used 2 different cables.

I read that the problem could be with my device (even though I used 3 devices)
i used usb host diagnostics app and this is the result:

[image]

first time i am trying to use communication from any kind in android.
thank you.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this problem?